# Java-How do I sequentially find the last occurrence of an element in an array that may not be filled?

Tags: java, arrays, search, comparator

I need to write a method that finds the index after the last occurrence of an element "item" in an array. I also have to find the index before the next largest item if item is not found. This is what I have so far.

```
public int findLast(E item)
    int index = array.length - 1;

    while (index >= 0 && comp.compare(item, array[index]) < 0) {
        index--;
    }

    return index;
}
```

I believe that this will find the index if there is a match within the array, and the next largest value if a match is not found, unless the array is not full. If some positions in the array are not filled at the end of the array and still null, the call to the comparator gives me a NullPointerException. I need to be able to work around that. Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT:
Here is some sample output. It may not make too much sense as this is a very watered down version of a method in a larger data structure that I need to build called a ragged arraylist.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.lang.String.compareTo(Unknown Source)
at RaggedArrayList$StringCmp.compare(RaggedArrayList.java:360)
at RaggedArrayList$StringCmp.compare(RaggedArrayList.java:1)
at RaggedArrayList.findEnd(RaggedArrayList.java:149)
at RaggedArrayList.add(RaggedArrayList.java:170)
at RaggedArrayList.main(RaggedArrayList.java:309)
```

Comment: does that code even compiles?

Comment: Could you provide some sample output

Comment: Yikes, edited out a pretty bad typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid accessing an uninitialized instance, add an "OR" with `array[index] == null` to your loop condition, like this:

```
public int findLast(E item)
    int index = array.length - 1;

    while (index >= 0 && (array[index] == null || comp.compare(item, array[index]) < 0)) {
        index--;      //  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    }

    return index;
}
```

A better approach would be passing the last index of the array where the data has been set. The best approach would be using collections that grow dynamically, rather than relying on arrays that cannot change in size.

Comment: This works! Unfortunately, due to constraints from this rather silly assignment's instructions, I can't use your undoubtedly better approach ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this this line :

```
int whereItIs = Arrays.asList(array).indexOf(item);
```